# Android appwidget sometimes changes preferences back to default

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have a couple of appwidgets released on the Android market and they work fine for the most part. However I have noticed that the preferences, saved using shared preferences, sometimes reset to the defaults. The defaults in this case are hard coded variables. The shared preferences as saved in an xml remain the same as saved by the user.

In one verifiable case the above problem, as well as other things such as buttons which stop responding, occurred after a device rebooted. I fixed that by creating a BroadcastReceiver which has an onReceive() method that will be activated by an intent filter in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

In other words the BroadcastReceiver will run after a reboot, which works great.

However the device still sometimes resets the preferences and I noticed this happens after a night or so of having been on standby. I suspect this is because the device (after some time, maybe due to going on standby) may restart the appwidget, which then will use the default preferences again. I tried to solve it by adding the following in the manifest as part of the BroadcastReceiver:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Full section reads:

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverName">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

I would like to know what may cause this problem and how can I detect it in the app and act accordingly, i.e. start the BroadcastReceiver and reload the preferences.

For completeness sake here is part of the (working) BroadcastReceiver code, I got the idea from [Service does not restart after "Clear Memory" + appWidget crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862882/service-does-not-restart-after-clear-memory-appwidget-crashes)

```
public class BroadcastReceiverName extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    /* stuff done here to reread shared preferences and refresh button's pending intents etc. */

    SharedPreferences config=context.getSharedPreferences(ExampleWidgetConfig.PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int poll=config.getInt(ExampleWidgetConfig.PREFS_UPDATE_RATE, ExampleWidgetProvider.poll);
    int alert=config.getInt(ExampleWidgetConfig.PREFS_ALERT, ExampleWidgetProvider.alert);
    int backg=config.getInt(ExampleWidgetConfig.PREFS_BACKG, ExampleWidgetProvider.backg);

    /* change hardcoded default preferences in case they differ from saved ones */
    ExampleWidgetProvider.poll=poll;
    ExampleWidgetProvider.alert=alert;
    ExampleWidgetProvider.backg=backg;

    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Code which saves the preferences. Please note that this code actually works and the problem is not that the preferences aren't saved or read correctly, but that hardcoded values in the app, which were changed to the user's values, are being changed back again (see above example).

```
/* change hardcoded values to user's settings */
ExampleWidgetProvider.poll=getpoll();
ExampleWidgetProvider.alert=getalert();
ExampleWidgetProvider.backg=getbackg();

/* store user settings we will continue to use these in the app */
SharedPreferences.Editor configEditor=config.edit();
configEditor.putInt(PREFS_UPDATE_RATE, ExampleWidgetProvider.poll);
configEditor.putInt(PREFS_ALERT, ExampleWidgetProvider.alert);
configEditor.putInt(PREFS_BACKG, ExampleWidgetProvider.backg);
configEditor.commit();
```

So I need to know how to find out when these hardcoded values reset to its default. I could work around it by reading the preferences xml every hour or so but that sounds like a stupid solution.

Comment: Can you show your preferences setup please?

Comment: Added code snippet. By the way the ExampleWidgetProvider.* variables are declared as public static int in the ExampleWidgetProvider class.

Comment: actually it's this bit I was interested in /* stuff done here to reread shared preferences and refresh button's pending intents etc. */

Comment: There is nothing of interested with regards to this problem, besides the shared preferences. It's just pending intent refresh and resetting of alarms and restarting of a service that runs at regular intervals. The poll, alert and backg variables aren't touched anymore.

Comment: so you don't call `setDefaultValues` I take it then

Comment: No I get the default values from hard coded variables.

Comment: When you say default value are you referring to the default value as set in the preference XML or as defined when you call `getInt`. If you don't know you can work this out by setting them to different values and seeing which one is present when you believe it is not using the persisted store.

Comment: I refer to the default values as defined with getInt, i.e. ExampleWidgetProvider.poll. One reason I know the values were reset to its defaults is that when I try to reconfigure the configuration screen shows the values as saved in the xml, however these values do not correspond with the behaviour. For example refresh time is 10 minutes by default, the configuration page shows it's set to 20 minutes by the user, however refresh is happening at 10 minutes. Once I save this configuration it is again back to 20 minutes... until half a day later after some standby time it once again is reset to 10.

Comment: If my answer doesn't help can you provide the code where you set your preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states:

> Parameters
>
> key   The name of the preference to retrieve. 
>   defValue  Value to return if this preference does not exist.
>
> Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. 
>   Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not
>   an int.

If the documentation is to be believed then the preference doesn't exist at all, you can test this by making your `getInt` values different to your values in your xml, if it is returning your `getInt` values you know the preferences don't exist.

In the above case your preferences must be being removed or weren't set up properly in the first place, this seems quite unlikely though.

Another thing you could look at is are you calling `commit` when you update your preferences or are your preferences being updated.

You could also try playing with the modes when you set up your preference, try `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` as the broad cast receiver is a separate process and presumably you are setting the preferences elsewhere and also try 'MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE'.

**UPDATE** from comments

Firstly, the code is a little confusing I guess because I can't see it all but you can't copy the whole project here so I will have to live with that.

This is how I understand the problem: You are setting these values in your preference and you can call `getInt` on these preferences at one point and it's correct, then after a certain event (perhaps triggered by going on stand by) you call `getInt` again and the preference is back at the default as specified in the preference.xml and not the default value passed when calling `getInt` (as this would suggest the preference doesn't exist).

I notice you are copying values to these ExampleWidgetProvider.* variables, are you certain that these aren't the correct values you are retrieving as preferences and whatever values exist in the preferences are never set correctly. I fail to see the point in having these variables as you are required to synchronize them when you change either one. If they are part of a work around then they should be removed so they don't convolute the original problem.

As I am sure you know; if you restart the app the preferences should be the same as before the restart as the preference values are persisted (presuming you have them configured correctly) and as it says in the documentation:

> **android:defaultValue**      The default value for the preference, which will
>   be set either if persistence is off or persistence is on and the
>   preference is not found in the persistent storage.

Which suggests that the preference is not getting reset to the original value but rather it doesn't exist for what ever reason (if it's this particular default value which keeps reappearing).

There exists the method `setDefaultValues(Context context, int resId, boolean readAgain=true)` but you said you aren't calling that. So it seems unlikely that the preference is getting reset but rather it is removed or never existed in the first place.

Comment: The problems is not that the preferences are not saved, they are saved correctly. The problem is that at some point (say after hours of standby) the preferences the user configured (which are saved) are reset. Note that the hard coded preference is changed to that which the user set, that variable is then used in the app. Say the original hardcoded value is 10, user changes it to 20 (and is saved as 20), app resets original hardcoded value to 10. That to me indicates the OS restarted the app and that's why it is using the original hardcoded values.

Comment: You're partially right, however I do not call getInt again after going in or coming out of standby. If that would be the case the preferences would be read from the xml and would be the correct ones (I am trying to find out how to detect this event). The default preferences are hard coded variables and never saved in an xml. These variables are changed when the user configures the app AND are saved. The problem is these variables are changed back to its hardcoded values at some point. I apologise for the confusing explanation. :-)

Comment: I guess when you say "If that would be the case the preferences would be read from the xml" you mean the file generated by the system which stores your preferences?

Comment: So why aren't you just reading from the preferences all the time, surely it's a question of scope why variable are being reset which would all be solved if values were persisted

Comment: Yes I mean the file generated by the system which stores the preferences. I could read the preferences at regular intervals, but I find that to be a bad solution. Because it basically means having to use polling (usually not a good way of doing things) in order to avoid the problem. I would like to find the solution instead. Besides what would the time interval be? What if the preferences are reset in between polling, will the user appreciate that the settings appear to be flipping back and forth?

Comment: But what I am suggesting is that when you need to set your preference you `putInt` and when you need to get it you `getInt` so there is only one copy of the value about, that is how preferences should really be used, what's the benefit of storing it in this variable?

Comment: The refresh rate can be as low as 2 minutes and each time it refreshes it needs to use the "alert" variable. It means in your solution it could be loading the preference from the filesystem every 2 minutes.I don't think that is how shared preferences should work in Android, unless you want to be able for the app to notice manual changes to the file but in that case it should check for the timestamp having been changed instead of reading the file contents itself. Anyways, it may be a better work around, so lacking any solution to the underlying problem I may as well implement that, thanks.

Comment: I tend to disagree, having this sort of caching mechanism will complicate matters (especially when you aren't in full control of the life cycles of your caching objects) so you have to weigh up the pros and cons, also android will have the preferences quite well optimized and 2 mins really isn't too bad. By the way I don't usually do this but I spent quite a while on this answer and we did thrash out some sort of result, would appreciate a plus one.

Comment: Yeah you gave me a good idea with regards to working around it and your argument in your last comment makes sense too. Thank you.